# How to replace last entered string in EditText of android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, android-edittext

I have two array of characters fetched from sqlite database. One array consists of normal fonts characters and other with style font characters.

The problem is that, when i select normal font character array and replaces the character entered in `EditText`. It works perfect, but after typing the certain character in `EditText` with another font character array in `EditText`. Then it replaces the old entered characters in `EditText`.

Here is the code I used to replace the characters in `EditText`.

```
watcher = new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence ss, int start, int before,
int count) {
    edt.removeTextChangedListener(watcher);

    String str = edt.getText().toString();

    String a = styleArray.get(0);
    String b = styleArray.get(1);
    String c = styleArray.get(2);

    str = str.replaceAll("a", a);
    str = str.replaceAll("b", b);
    str = str.replaceAll("c", c);

    edt.setText(str);
    edt.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    int position = edt.getText().length();

    Editable ed = edt.getText();

    Selection.setSelection(ed, position);
}
};
```

The two array fetched from database are:

```
a. {a,b,c}
b. {ⓐ, ⓑ, ⓒ}
```

Example: When I select the first array {a,b,c} and the text suppose entered in `EditText` box is "abc". From here its ok. But when I select another array of font character {ⓐ, ⓑ, ⓒ} and enter the text in edittext, then result must be this "abcⓐⓑⓒ". Instead of this result "abcⓐⓑⓒ" I am getting "ⓐⓑⓒⓐⓑⓒ". It also replaces the old entered characters. So, what is the logic behind this? I tried to much but didn't find the solution.

Comment: @pareshmayani Help me out...

Comment: It seems that EditText only allows one TypeFace which is the equivalent of `android:fontFamily`. So it gets overrided when you paste text with other font in it, I guess.